# ValueError: ndarray is not C-contiguous

Tags: python, machine-learning

I'm Daisuke Murakami.
I have a trouble about a GridsearchCV. 
I want to use RMSE as loss function. Then, I wrote the following code.

```
def Ridge_tool(df_train,df_test):
    df_train = df_train.drop("id",axis=1)
    df_test = df_test.drop("id",axis=1)

    param_grid = {"alpha": [0.01,0.1,1],
                  "solver": ["auto","svd","cholesky","lsqr","sparse_cg","sag","saga"]}
    rmse = make_scorer(rmse_func, greater_is_better=False)
    lr = Ridge(normalize = True,random_state=0)
    lr_grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=lr,param_grid = param_grid,scoring=rmse,cv = 5,n_jobs =-1)
    lr_grid.fit(df_train[df_train.columns[df_train.columns != "y"]], df_train["y"])
    lr_grid_best = lr_grid.best_estimator_ 
    print("Best Model Parameter: ",lr_grid.best_params_)
    print("Best Model Score    : ",lr_grid.best_score_)
    pred = lr_grid_best.predict(df_test)
    return pred

def rmse_func(y_true,y_pred):
    loss = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred))
    return  loss
```

But,I got error "ValueError: ndarray is not C-contiguous".
I cant understand this error. and, I can't find a solution.
Can anyone tell me the reason for this error if possible....

Comment: Please provide ``df_train`` and ``df_test`` to make it reproductible (when generating my own data, I could not reproduce the error).

Comment: Thank you for reply. I'm sorry, I cant give the data directly because of the regulations. but,I solve this problem by myself.

Comment: The data is for competition about  j-league in SIGNATE.(https://signate.jp/competitions/27/data)

Comment: I eliminate "sag" and "saga" from "solver" in param_grid. Then,It's no problem. Maybe, this way is not compatible for my data.